# Socket.io: how to emit event to room inside http request handler

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

`io.to(roomId).emit('message', text)` not working when used inside http request handler. But general event `io.emit('message', text)` works. I can't figure it out if it's a problem of instance, or problem of socket client that not listening to events properly.

So, how can I emit event to specific room, while being in other files (route handlers etc)?

Main file running app:

```
import { createServer } from "http";
import app from "./app";
import config from "./utills/config";
import logger from "./utills/logger";
import initWebsockets from "./websockets/server";

const server = createServer(app);

server.listen(config.PORT, () => {
  logger.info(`server running on port ${config.PORT}`);
});

initWebsockets(server);
```

`websockets/server.ts` file

```
import { SocketIOService } from "./service";

export default (expressServer) => {
  SocketIOService.instance().initialize(expressServer);

  const io = SocketIOService.instance().getServer();

  io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
    socket.on("join", async ({ ...roomObject }) => {
      console.log("roomObject", roomObject);
      const room = roomObject.chatId;
      console.log("joining room", room);
      socket.join(room);
      SocketIOService.instance()
        .getServer()
        .to(room)
        .emit("message", "Welcome to chat room");
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("Client disconnected");
    });
  });

  return io;
};
```

`websockets/service.ts`

```
import { Server, ServerOptions } from "socket.io";
import { Server as HttpServer } from "http";

export class SocketIOService {
  private static _instance: SocketIOService | undefined;
  private static server: Server | undefined;

  private constructor() {
    // Private constructor ensures singleton instance
  }

  static instance(): SocketIOService {
    if (!this._instance) {
      return new SocketIOService();
    }

    return this._instance;
  }

  initialize(httpServer: HttpServer, opts?: Partial<ServerOptions>) {
    SocketIOService.server = new Server(httpServer, opts);

    return SocketIOService.server;
  }

  ready() {
    return SocketIOService.server !== null;
  }

  getServer(): Server {
    if (!SocketIOService.server) {
      throw new Error("IO server requested before initialization");
    }

    return SocketIOService.server;
  }
}
```

And the function that is called inside POST request handler

```
export const sendNewMessageEvent = (conversationId, _message) => {
  console.log("sending ws event to room:", conversationId);
  const socketIO = SocketIOService.instance().getServer();
  if (SocketIOService.instance().ready()) {
    socketIO.to(conversationId).emit("message", "room message"); // clients not receiving this one
    socketIO.emit("message", "general message"); // clients receiving this one
  } else {
    console.log("socket not ready");
  }
};
```

When testing with postman, i receive only general socket events (for react app also same, even after joining room)
[image]

Comment: What are `roomObject` and the `conversationId` when testing this?

Comment: @Matt it's just an object containing the chatId (which is used as an id of the room)

Comment: you can see the usage of `join` emit in the postman screenshot.

Comment: Cool, I didn't get a chance to elaborate, but as the singleton looked ok and the plain `emit` was working I guessed it might be related to the id's

Answer (score 0):

LOL, after hours of debugging i figured it out.

The reason was because `sendNewMessageEvent` received `conversationId` as an `Types.ObjectId`, not a string.